# How to define margin for pdf doc?

Tags: margins, geometry, marginpar, document-configuration, typearea

I have the problem that my output pdf has the wrong margin between left and right. you can see it in the pic below:
[image]

The problem is, I need the opposite way. left have to be wide and right narrow. How can I change this?

Here is a configuration of the template:

```
\geometry{%
%%% Paper size
   a4paper, % Andere a0paper, a1paper, a2paper, a3paper, , a5paper, a6paper,
            % b0paper, b1paper, b2paper, b3paper, b4paper, b5paper, b6paper
            % letterpaper, executivepaper, legalpaper
   portrait,    % Hochformat
   lines=45,       % enables users to specify \textheight by the number of lines
   ignoreall,     % sets both ignoreheadfoot and ignoremp to true
   heightrounded, % This option rounds \textheight to n-times (n: an integer) of \baselineskip
   twoside,       % switches on twoside mode with left and right margins swapped on verso pages.
   bindingoffset=5mm,  % removes a specified space for binding
   marginparwidth=0pt, % width of the marginal notes
   textwidth=400pt,   % sets \textwidth directly
}
```

and I'm found a definition of typearea what is used automatically:

```
\KOMAoptions{% (most options are for package typearea)
   twoside=true, % two side layout (alternating margins, standard in books)
   twocolumn=false, % (true)
   headinclude=false,%
   footinclude=false,%
   mpinclude=false,%
   headlines=2.1,%
   headsepline=true,%
   footsepline=false,%
   parskip=half+,% false(default=1em indent),full[-+*], half[-+*]
   cleardoublepage=empty %plain, headings
}%
```

Comment: Do you really need the opposite way? *This* is the normal layout in two-sid option, since when you open a book,  the right margin of the even page and the left margin of the odd page add up to a double blank space. That said, if you really  want it the way you describe, use the `geometry` package.

Comment: @Bernard The normal way is to start with the right page. That means you need on the left side more margin, right?

Comment: @Bernard In my case, when I open the thesis the titlepage has a smaller margin on the left but it has to be on the right smaller.

Comment: you can try `\geometry{...,inner=5cm,outer=2cm}` or `\geometry{...,hmarginratio=3:1}`

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe you need equal margins for the title page, rather than smaller right margin (unless some weird specification from your university requires that). Anyway, this is easy with `geometry`: simply use `\newgeometry{leftmargin=…,rightmargin=…}` before your titlepage, and `\restoregeometry` afterwards.

Comment: Consider how this title page will appear. If it is a 'cover page' the way we have a cover on a book, then the typeblock should be centred with respect to the physical page. However, it is the 'title page' inside a bound thesis/book, then you want the margins to match the other pages of the thesis/book (i.e., smaller inner margin than outer margin on a 'recto' page). In the second case, centering the typeblock would look quite strange.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just to allow room for the binding? If so, you should specify a binding offset so that whichever package you use to layout the page knows to eliminate that much space on the left of odd pages and the right of even ones. Guidelines made for word processors may well describe this as part of the 'margin', but it is not really part of the page at all.